# Extendendo função javascript com parametros

Tags: javascript, funções

Gostaria de saber se é possível extender uma função do javascript sem precisar repetir os parametros, como se fosse uma construtor, uso atualmente assim:

```
function DefaultRun(args1,args2) {
}

function Run(args1, args2){
    DefaultRun.call(this,
        args1,
        args2);
}

Run.prototype = Object.create(DefaultRun.prototype);
```

Teria alguma forma de fazer isso?

```
function DefaultRun(args1, args2, args3) {
}

function Run(){
    DefaultRun.call(this);
}

Run.prototype = Object.create(DefaultRun.prototype);
```

Ou seja, adicionar um argumento no pai sempre precisar adicionar em todos os seus filhos. Seria possivel?

Edit ----

Preciso disso, pois uso essa função em vários arquivos que possuem um controller em angularjs, nesse estilo:

```
function Run(){
    DefaultRun.call(this, ...arguments);
}

Run.prototype = Object.create(DefaultRun.prototype);

angular.module("APP").run(Run);
```

No entanto para por exemplo utilizar o `$scope`, eu preciso definir isso na função Run, ou seja, se preciso adicionar algum parametro, irei precisar adicionar em todos os arquivos que utilizam ele como Pai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em JavaScript, quando você invoca uma função, todos os argumentos são armazenados em um objeto/array com o nome arguments, independente de você ter declarado os parâmetros ou não, então eu suponho que usando `DefaultRun.call(this, ...arguments);` você enviaria automaticamente todos os argumentos para o construtor pai, gerando um comportamento similar ao que você deseja.

Comment: Ai que ta o problema, eu preciso centralizar isso. Os filhos são chamados em diversos lugares, preciso conseguir gerenciar isso pelo Pai.

Comment: @Kol Então nem eu nem o colega que respondeu entendemos sua dúvida... Pode por favor [editar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/338384/edit) e informar mais detalhes? Explicar o caso de uso ajuda, talvez a solução seja diferente do que você imagina.

Comment: A menos que eu tenha entendido errado, isso é exatamente o que a função sugerida faz. "..." é o operador de resto, ele irá enviar o primeiro item do array como primeiro argumento, o segundo como segundo, o terceiro como terceiro, e assim por diante. Se o objeto pai for receber muitos argumentos, recomendo reformular seu construtor para receber apenas um JSON, dessa forma você não precisará se preocupar com a estrutura mais tarde.